# How do I run a command on an already existing Docker container?

Tags: docker

I created a container with `-d` so it's not interactive.

```
docker run -d shykes/pybuilder bin/bash
```

I see that the container has exited:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
d6c45e8cc5f0        shykes/pybuilder:latest   "bin/bash"          41 minutes ago      Exited (0) 2 seconds ago                        clever_bardeen
```

Now I would like to run occasional commands on the machine and exit. Just to get the response.

I tried to start the machine. I tried attaching. I thought I could call `run` with a container, but that does not seem to be allowed. Using `start` just seems to run and then exist quickly.

I'd like to get back into interactive mode after exiting.

I tried:

```
docker attach d6c45e8cc5f0
```

But I get:

```
2014/10/01 22:33:34 You cannot attach to a stopped container, start it first
```

But if I start it, it exits anyway. Catch 22. I can't win.

Comment: how did you know that the docker container had exited?  what command did you run?

Comment: `docker container ls -a`

Comment: If you just need the file system: [*How to start a stopped Docker container with a different command?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353055/how-to-start-a-stopped-docker-container-with-a-different-command) (Note that environment variables and other things in memory are already lost when the container stopped.)

Answer (score 635, accepted):

In October 2014 the [Docker team introduced `docker exec` command](http://blog.docker.com/2014/10/docker-1-3-signed-images-process-injection-security-options-mac-shared-directories/): https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

So now you can run any command in a running container just knowing its ID (or name):

```
docker exec -it <container_id_or_name> echo "Hello from container!"
```

Note that `exec` command works only on already running container. If the container is currently stopped, you need to first run it with the following command:

```
docker run -it -d shykes/pybuilder /bin/bash
```

The most important thing here is the `-d` option, which stands for `detached`. It means that the command you initially provided to the container (`/bin/bash`) will be run in the background and the container will not *stop immediately*.

Comment: This doesn't work on a stopped container, only a running one. So if you have a container that immediately stops itself, as in the question, this won't actually work to get something else running inside it.

Comment: @interfect is right, and CDR LDN has a more comprehensive answer.

Comment: So, the high-level question was the same question I was seeking an answer to "How to run a command on an already existing docker container?" and this solution was the exact solution I was looking for. I didn't need to add `-it` to run a command in the docker container. I understand the contextual confusion, but this is the solution I needed for that exact question. Not sure what that means for the "correct" answer, perhaps the title should be changed? This gets my upvote either way.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke Btw this person's username has changed from `CDR LDN` to `cdrev` for the answer below (http://stackoverflow.com/a/26181666/149428).

Comment: Why passing `-it`?

Comment: omg why is this so complicated? Seems like the most basic thing you'd need to do. We must not be using it the way they intend.

Comment: This still doesn't answer how to attach to a container that wasn't ``docker run`` with ``-it`` in the first place...

Question asks about a container that exits and is down because even with ``bash`` it simply exits because it doesn't keep STDIN open with ``-i``

Comment: "docker run -it -d shykes/pybuilder /bin/bash"  created another container instance

Comment: I had an error "-bash: !": event not found" until I have removed exclamation mark from "Hello form container"

Comment: This is incorrect answer. Please check the asnwer by @Adam below.

Comment: all I do is see **dquote>** when exec that?

Comment: Not working for me, the "docker run" command tries to start a new container, instead of starting the exiting one.

Comment: @AshishPratap I think that is exactly what `docker run` is supposed to do - to start up a _new_ container. And if you want to start an existing container, you should use `docker start <container_name_or_id>`. (Note that it's just from the top of my head, as I haven't used docker for some time already.)
Then on the running container you can use `docker exec ...`. Hope this helps.

Comment: but the continer has to be running to execute                                                       "docker exec -it <container_id or name> bash"                                                           i choose bash for this example if the container is not running                         "docker run -it ubuntu bash" and then you start a new container if you don't have one

Answer (score 314):

Your container will **exit** as the command you gave it will end. Use the following options to keep it live:

- `-i` Keep STDIN open even if not attached.
- `-t` Allocate a pseudo-TTY.

So your new `run` command is:

```
docker run -it -d shykes/pybuilder bin/bash
```

If you would like to attach to an already running container:

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash
```

In these examples `/bin/bash` is used as the command.

Comment: Tried `docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash -c "export VAR=1 && echo $VAR"` and printed empty variable (expected `1`). What am I missing?

Comment: after running 'docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash' it goes to the bash correctly but cannot interact with it.

Comment: But If I am using docker-compose the `-it` is not available.

Answer (score 211):

So I think the answer is simpler than many misleading answers above.

**To start an existing container which is stopped**

```
docker start <container-name/ID>
```

**To stop a running container**

```
docker stop <container-name/ID>
```

**Then to login to the interactive shell of a container**

```
docker exec -it <container-name/ID> bash
```

**To start an existing container and attach to it in one command**

```
docker start -ai <container-name/ID>
```

Beware, this will stop the container on exit. But in general, you need to start the container, attach and stop it after you are done.

Comment: docker attach <container-name/ID> which is running

Comment: @Peter T.  Actually, I found your answer a lot more concise than what others have provided. I don't understand why people prefer to complicate a very simple question. Thanks Peter this answer.

Comment: this requires that when you did docker create, you did it with -it  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45216612/docker-getting-exited-just-after-start  otherwise it won't start.. so you'd do docker start <container-id> and then docker ps -l and you'd see it's not up after the start. and then the attach would fail. So gotta create with -it too.

Comment: The question title is misleading, and the author should've approved this as the correct answer.

Comment: I execute ```docker start -ai <ID>``` and it stops instantly. So I cannot enter insede container.  How should the container be created so that it will allow entry?

Comment: definitely the top answer!

Answer (score 106):

To expand on katrmr's answer, if the container is stopped and can't be started due to an error, you'll need to `commit` it to an image. Then you can launch bash in the new image:

```
docker commit [CONTAINER_ID] temporary_image
docker run --entrypoint=bash -it temporary_image
```

Comment: FYI, I do this so much that I've put together a command called `dshell` to do it automatically in a variety of situations - https://github.com/avirshup/docker-cli-sugar

Answer (score 44):

Some of the answers here are misleading because they concern containers that are running, not stopped.

Sven Dowideit explained on the Docker forum that containers are bound to their process (and Docker can't change the process of a stopped container, seemingly due at least to its internal structure: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1437). So, basically the only option is to `commit` the container to an image and `run` it with a different command.

See https://forums.docker.com/t/run-command-in-stopped-container/343
(I believe the "`ENTRYPOINT` with arguments" approach wouldn't work either, since you still wouldn't be able to change the arguments to a stopped container.)

Comment: Notice: running `bin/bash` without `-it` wouldn't change anything in the container, so committing it isn't really necessary and CDR LDN gives the right answer for the OP's particular situation. Still, `commit` is the answer to the technical problem of how to change the container process.

Comment: The comment by candlerb at run-command-in-stopped-container suggesting to use a throwaway image with the volume from the inactive container worked for me: docker run --rm --volumes-from CONTAINER -i busybox tar cO /var/DIR | gzip -c > ~/mydir_backup.tgz

Comment: This is the actual answer to the question asked. Containers are bound to their process, so the command can't be changed.

Answer (score 25):

I had to use bash -c to run my command:
`docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID bash -c "mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql mysql"`

Comment: -c worked for me. wonder why bash alone wouldn't work (doesn't get a prompt)

Answer (score 19):

Creating a container and sending commands to it, one by one:

```
docker create --name=my_new_container -it ubuntu
docker start my_new_container
// ps -a says 'Up X seconds'
docker exec my_new_container /path/to/my/command
// ps -a still says 'Up X+Y seconds'
docker exec my_new_container /path/to/another/command
```

Comment: This is the good answer to the question. If you want to start the container after creation and be able to "docker exec" commands into it, you have to create it with the "-it" flags in the docker create command.

Answer (score 10):

If you are trying to run shell script, you need run it as bash.

```
docker exec -it containerid bash -c /path/to/your/script.sh
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to do, thank you so much

Answer (score 8):

This is a combined answer I made up using the CDR LDN answer above and the answer I found [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8755#issuecomment-60707979).

The following example starts an Arch Linux container from an image, and then installs `git` on that container using the `pacman` tool:

```
sudo docker run -it -d archlinux /bin/bash
sudo docker ps -l
sudo docker exec -it [container_ID] script /dev/null -c "pacman -S git --noconfirm"
```

That is all.

Answer (score 8):

**Pipe a command to `docker exec bash` stdin**

Must remove the `-t` for it to work:

```
echo 'touch myfile' | docker exec -i CONTAINER_NAME bash
```

This can be more convenient that using CLI options sometimes.

Tested with:

```
docker run --name ub16 -it ubuntu:16.04 bash
```

then on another shell:

```
echo 'touch myfile' | docker exec -i ub16 bash
```

Then on first shell:

```
ls -l myfile
```

Tested on Docker 1.13.1, Ubuntu 16.04 host.

Comment: You don't need sudo. You just need to be in the docker group.

Answer (score 8):

I would like to note that the top answer is a little misleading.

The issue with executing `docker run` is that a new container is created every time. However, there are cases where we would like to revisit old containers or not take up space with new containers.

(Given `clever_bardeen` is the name of the container created...)

In OP's case, make sure the docker image is first running by executing the following command:

```sh
docker start clever_bardeen
```

Then, execute the docker container using the following command:

```sh
docker exec -it clever_bardeen /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 5):

I usually use this:

```
    docker exec -it my-container-name bash
```

to continuously interact with a running container.

Comment: The whole point is that, you cannot run this command on a exited container. It shows the following error:

Error response from daemon: Container 31ed0... is not running

Comment: @AshishPratap What a strange error! I just runned "docker exec -it e47e2ece292a bash" and it works properly. Maybe you need to update the Docker?

Comment: are you sure that when you ran this command your container was not in running state already?

Comment: @AshishPratap Ooo you are right, my mistake. This command can not be executed in a stopped container

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the image is using the default entrypoint `/bin/sh -c`, running `/bin/bash` will exit  immediately in daemon mode (`-d`). If you want this container to run an interactive shell, use `-it` instead of `-d`. If you want to execute arbitrary commands in a container usually executing another process, you might want to try `nsenter` or `nsinit`.  Have a look at https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/07/enter-docker-container/ for the details.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it is impossible to override `ENTRYPOINT` with arguments with `docker run --entrypoint` to achieve this goal.

> Note: you can override the ENTRYPOINT setting using --entrypoint, but
>   this can only set the binary to exec (no sh -c will be used).

Answer (score 2):

**For Mac:**

```
$ docker exec -it <container-name> sh
```

if you want to connect as root user:

```
$ docker exec -u 0 -it <container-name> sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: start and attach at the same time. In this case you are doing exactly what you asked for.

```
docker start <CONTAINER_ID/CONTAINER_NAME> && docker attach <CONTAINER_ID/CONTAINER_NAME>
```

make sure to change `<CONTAINER_ID/CONTAINER_NAME>`

Answer (score 1):

I am running windows container and I need to look inside the docker container for files and folder created and copied.

In order to do that I used following docker entrypoint command to get the command prompt running inside the container or attach to the container.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

That helped me both to the command prompt attach to container and to keep the container a live. :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I figured that I had to use the `-i` [option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/#options) when I create a container to be able to keep it running (not exiting immediately) when I start it using the `docker start <container_name/container_id>` command.

Let's say, I want to run an Ubuntu container. Let's try creating the container with and without the `-i` option to see the difference in action.

*I'll also use `-t` option to see a pseudo-terminal when I run the `docker attach <container_name/container_id>` command to attach to the container.*

## Creating a container without the `-i` option

```bash
# Listing existing images
$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID   CREATED   SIZE

# Listing existing containers
$ docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES

# Pulling ubuntu image from the Docker Hub
$ docker pull ubuntu
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/ubuntu
a48641193673: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:6042500cf4b44023ea1894effe7890666b0c5c7871ed83a97c36c76ae560bb9b
Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:latest
docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest

# Listing existing images
$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
ubuntu       latest    174c8c134b2a   3 weeks ago   77.9MB

# Creating a container from the ubuntu image without the `-i` option
$ docker create ubuntu
e1a1e3a8996a268d3cad7b0f7dc35a57f308034f05fe34436ad38d93559e516a

# Listing existing containers
$ docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND       CREATED         STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
e1a1e3a8996a   ubuntu    "/bin/bash"   3 seconds ago   Created             recursing_mcnulty

# Starting the container named "recursing_mcnulty"
$ docker start recursing_mcnulty
recursing_mcnulty

# Listing existing containers (STATUS says Exited because it was started and then exited immediately)
$ docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND       CREATED         STATUS                     PORTS     NAMES
e1a1e3a8996a   ubuntu    "/bin/bash"   3 minutes ago   Exited (0) 7 seconds ago             recursing_mcnulty

# Attaching to the container named "recursing_mcnulty" won't work obviously
$ docker attach recursing_mcnulty
You cannot attach to a stopped container, start it first
```

## Creating a container with the `-i` option

```bash
# Listing existing images
$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
ubuntu       latest    174c8c134b2a   3 weeks ago   77.9MB

# Listing existing containers
$ docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND       CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS     NAMES
e1a1e3a8996a   ubuntu    "/bin/bash"   5 minutes ago    Exited (0) 2 minutes ago              recursing_mcnulty

# Creating a container from the ubuntu image with the `-i` option
$ docker create -it ubuntu
a9a61f197058538e11e9c4e1327f270ca391eb461cb46ea5e140d3cf260c7ac3

# Listing existing containers
$ docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND       CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS     NAMES
a9a61f197058   ubuntu    "/bin/bash"   13 seconds ago   Created                               vigorous_mendeleev
e1a1e3a8996a   ubuntu    "/bin/bash"   7 minutes ago    Exited (0) 5 minutes ago              recursing_mcnulty

# Starting the container named "vigorous_mendeleev"
$ docker start vigorous_mendeleev
vigorous_mendeleev

# Listing existing containers (STATUS says Up this time)
$ docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND       CREATED              STATUS                      PORTS     NAMES
a9a61f197058   ubuntu    "/bin/bash"   About a minute ago   Up 13 seconds                         vigorous_mendeleev
e1a1e3a8996a   ubuntu    "/bin/bash"   8 minutes ago        Exited (0) 6 minutes ago              recursing_mcnulty

# Attaching to the container named "vigorous_mendeleev" will work now
$ docker attach vigorous_mendeleev
root@a9a61f197058:/# 

# And the shell is interactive as well
root@a9a61f197058:/# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib32  lib64  libx32  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# docker exec -d container_id command
```

Ex:

```
# docker exec -d xcdefrdtt service jira stop
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to resume and access the most recently exited container:

```
docker start -a -i `docker ps -q -l`
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution that solved a similar problem for me:

```
docker run --interactive --tty <name_of_image>
```