# Docker start container with custom command

Tags: docker

How can existing docker container be started (in sense of  `docker start`) with customizations of `docker run` like

- `--entrypoint`
- `--env`
- `--volume`

multiple times?

I want to avoid a [hack of changing docker config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32353134/639687) that requires restart of docker daemon.

A clumsy way I found is to commit current container before each run and use `docker run` to start it.

Comment: How about simply defining a shell alias?

Comment: Not sure what you are getting at, can you describe the use case for what you are doing? If we know what you are trying to do, there might be an easier approach

Answer (score 0):

If you need to start the same container automatically after termination, you may take a look on [--restart](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#restart-policies-restart) option