# docker exit immediately after launching apache and neo4j

Tags: docker, neo4j, apache2

I have a script `/init` that launches apache and neo4j. This script is already in the image `ubuntu:14`. The following is the content of `/init`:

```
service apache2 start
service neo4j start
```

From this image, I am creating another image with the following dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:v14
EXPOSE 80 80
ENTRYPOINT ["/init"]
```

When I run the command `docker run -d ubuntu:v15`, the container starts and then exit. As far as I understood, `-d` option runs the container in the background. Also, the script`\init` launches two daemons. **Why does the container exit ?**

Comment: Your script is pid 1, when pid 1 exits, the container dies. Try tailing the logs or something ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49508874/how-do-avoid-a-docker-container-stop-after-the-application-is-stopped-descriptio/49509014#49509014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, I think your first problem is the `#!` in `init` file, if you did not add something like `#!/bin/bash` at the start, container will complain like next:

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~$ docker logs priceless_tu
standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

But even you fix above problem, you will still can't start your container, the reason same as other folks said: the PID 1 should always there, in your case after `service xxx start` finish, the PID 1 exit which will also result in container exit.

So, to conquer this problem you should set one command never exit, a minimal workable example for your reference:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y apache2

COPY init /
RUN chmod +x /init

EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["/init"]
```

**init:**

```
#!/bin/bash

# you can add other service start here
# e.g. service neo4j start as you like if you have installed it already

# next will make apache run in foreground, so PID1 not exit.
/usr/sbin/apache2ctl -DFOREGROUND
```

Answer (score 1):

When your Dockerfile specifies an ENTRYPOINT, the lifetime of the container is exactly the length of whatever its process is.  Generally the behavior of `service ... start` is to start the service as a background process and then return immediately; so your `/init` script runs the two `service` commands and completes, and now that the entrypoint process is completed, the container exits.

Generally accepted best practice is to run only one process in a container.  That's especially true when one of the processes is a database.  In your case there are standard Docker Hub [Apache `httpd`](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/) and [`neo4j`](https://hub.docker.com/_/neo4j) images, so I'd start by using an orchestration tool like [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/) to run those two containers side-by-side.