# ENTRYPOINT, CMD and run priorities

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to figure out the ordering and priority of Dockerfile entrypoint, cmd and run. And additionally how each persists over stopping and restarting the container.

Supposing:

A docker container is configured to have an entrypoint `program_1`. It is then started with `docker run my_container program_2`.

The container is then stopped and restarted with `docker stop my_container` `docker start my_container`.

Which and in what order will the commands be run?

I'm specifically interested in the whether the command from `docker run` will persist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between CMD and ENTRYPOINT in a Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile)

Comment: Also, if you stop a container and then start it again it uses the same ENTRYPOINT and CMD. There are ways to change the command, but not for the faint of heart. For example, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32353134/5753290.

Comment: @Andrew I'm specifically wondering regarding the run command, whether it will persist over restarts

Comment: Yes, it is persisted. For example:

    $ docker run --name run-test -dt debian /bin/sh -c "while [ true ]; do date; sleep 5; done"
    b5823b0e1d135e5535e1845f96916c870294595a1f0ed70ca59dcda99572cb0e
    $ docker logs run-test
    Thu Sep 20 20:48:51 UTC 2018
    $ docker stop run-test
    run-test
    $ sleep 60 && docker start run-test && docker logs -f run-test
    run-test
    Thu Sep 20 20:48:51 UTC 2018
    Thu Sep 20 20:48:56 UTC 2018

Putting code in the comment did not work as I expected, but please let me know if you'd like me to put it in an answer.