# Translate docker run into subcomponents

Tags: docker, docker-run, gitleaks

I have this docker run command:

```
docker run --rm --name=gitleaks \
   -v "/keys/ssh/values:/root/.ssh"  \
   zricethezav/gitleaks  \
   --ssh-key='bucket' \
   --repo "$line"
```

I tranlated it to this:

```
  docker create zricethezav/gitleaks --name=gitleaks
  docker cp /keys/ssh/values gitleaks:/root/.ssh
  docker start gitleaks  --ssh-key='bucket' --repo "$line"
```

but it gives me this error:

> ```
> Error: No such container:path: gitleaks:/root
> unknown flag: --ssh-key
> ```

Does anybody know where I went wrong? Ultimately I am calling docker run from within a running container and am having trouble sharing files, so trying to get `docker cp` to work.

Comment: as you can see I also failed to translate the `--rm` flag from docker run to the 3 subcommands, not sure where to put that

Comment: I do believe that when you start a container you start it at the same configuration you created it and you can't pass it parameters. All parameters should be passed to the create command.

Answer (score 7):

Issue is with your first and second command syntax.

```
docker create zricethezav/gitleaks --name=gitleaks
```

`--name` should be **before image name**, otherwise `docker create` will interpret it as *COMMAND* argument instead of *OPTIONS flag*.

```
 docker start gitleaks --ssh-key='bucket' --repo "$line"
```

I understand you want to run the image with parameters --ssh-key and --repo, however it's not possible with [`docker start`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/start/) command. If you want to have these parameters passed to the process run by the image, you should pas these parameters to `docker create` or `docker run` command after the image name.

So you should do:

```
# Mind the --name before the image name
docker create --name=gitleaks zricethezav/gitleaks --ssh-key='bucket' --repo "$line"
docker cp /keys/ssh/values gitleaks:/root/.ssh
docker start gitleaks
```

**Explanations for docker create:**

[`docker create` usage](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/) is:

```
docker create [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

Where `OPTIONS` flags should be specified before `IMAGE`, and everything after `IMAGE` will be interpreted as `COMMAND` and `ARG...`.

When you are running

```
docker create zricethezav/gitleaks --name=gitleaks
```

You are in fact passing `--name=gitleaks` as `COMMAND` which will override default image command (the one tipycally provided by `CMD` in Dockerfile), where you probably want to pass it as `OPTIONS`. For example, if you run:

```
docker create alpine --name=foobar
docker create --name=foobar alpine
```

`docker ps -a` output will look like:

```
IMAGE        COMMAND              NAMES
alpine       "/bin/sh"            foobar
alpine       "--name=foobar"      quirky_varahamihira
```

If you want to pass both `OPTIONS` and `COMMAND`, you must specify `OPTIONS` before the image name and `COMMAND` after the image name.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the docker container ID not its name for the copy.

The ID is returned when creating the container,so:

```sh
ID=$(docker create zricethezav/gitleaks --name=gitleaks)
docker cp /keys/ssh/values ${ID}:/root/.ssh
```

If you've already created the container, you can:

```sh
ID=$(docker inspect gitleaks --format="{{.ID}}")
```

But, @mihai is correct and I'm unsure how you'd be able to then configure the container for the start.

<strike>I think the correct approach to this is to `FROM:gitleaks` and build your own image (Dockerfile) that adds your keys.</strike>

The documentation provides an explanation for using a GitHub token to access private repos:

https://github.com/zricethezav/gitleaks#docker-usage-examples

Comment: I am willing to bet you can use the container name not just the id, but I haven't checked

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** The ideal translation would be

```sh
docker create --rm --name=gitleaks zricethezav/gitleaks --ssh-key='bucket' --repo "$line"
docker cp /keys/ssh/values gitleaks:/root/.ssh
docker start gitleaks
```

---

(X) 1. `docker create zricethezav/gitleaks --name=gitleaks`

Your translation does not match the [usage description](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/) of `docker create`.

```sh
docker create [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

So, you need to swap your option `--name=gitleaks` with the image name:

```sh
docker create --name=gitleaks zricethezav/gitleaks
```

(✓) 2. `docker cp /keys/ssh/values gitleaks:/root/.ssh`

This will be executed successfully.

(X) 3. `docker start gitleaks --ssh-key='bucket' --repo "$line"`

This will throw an error saying:

```
unknown flag: --ssh-key
```

According [to usage description](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/start/) of `docker start`, it is not possible to pass `command` nor `argument` to an already existing container.

You have two alternatives though to overcome this problem:

1. Append `--ssh-key='bucket' --repo "$line"` to `docker create --name=gitleaks zricethezav/gitleaks`
2. Or if you are bored, you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353055/how-to-start-a-stopped-docker-container-with-a-different-command) instead.

> as you can see I also failed to translate the --rm flag from docker run to the 3 subcommands, not sure where to put that

The `--rm` option is available for [docker create](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/), so you should put it there. And also, as *Mihai* mentioned, you should pass your arguments (`--ssh-key` etc.) while running `docker create`:

```
docker create --rm --name=gitleaks zricethezav/gitleaks --ssh-key='bucket' --repo "$line"
```