# Interactive mode is ignored for containers ran without it

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-container

I'm trying to understand the way `docker container start` works and use the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

WORKDIR /root

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
                      curl \
                      gnupg2 \
                      git

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Now I build an image as

```
docker image build -t tst .
```

and run the container as follows:

```
docker container run -d tst
```

I run it without interactive mode so it exited as soon as the command execution completes. Now I tried to start this container in an interactive mode:

```
docker container start -i 57806f93e42c
```

But it immediately exits as it would run non-interactively:

```
STATUS                                                                                                   
Exited (0) 9 seconds ago
```

Is there a way to override "interactiveness" for an already created container?

Comment: @LinPy `-t` flag has no effect on the `start` command. `unknown shorthand flag: 't' in -t See 'docker container start --help'.` `-i` can be specified though.

Comment: Sorry I did not notice that start. I think there is no way to prevent it to stop

Comment: @LinPy  But what I am actually concerned about is if it is possible to use `start -i` for containers that were created without `-i`. Maybe some workarounds?

Comment: yes only if the image has an Entrypoint see my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58500866/how-to-restart-an-existing-mongodb-docker-container-with-a-new-flags-to-daemon/58501700#58501700

Comment: Do docker exec -it  57806f93e42c bash

Answer (score 1):

This is because you container run in detach mode without [allocating pseudo-TTY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/), as bash is the main process of your container so it will exit immediately.

> That means, when run in background (-d), the shell exits immediately.

[Docker container will automatically stop after "docker run -d"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209776/docker-container-will-automatically-stop-after-docker-run-d/46898038)

All you need to allocate pseudo-tty

```
docker container run -dit tst
```

and the next command

```
docker container start -i 57806f93e42c
```

you just trying to start the stoped container, but again it will exit immediately, it does not create new container but trying to start stopped container.

```
docker container stop
```

> Start one or more stopped containers

[container_start](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_start/)