# How can I run a command in github action service containers?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, github-actions, minio

I am using minio to create an s3 like object-store server and
I want to test some code against this server during my ci cd process.
Using Github actions, I tried to add minio as service in the workflow file but since minio requires a command and some arguments I can't actually run it using this mechanism.
This is the part of the relevant configuration from my ci.yml:

```
minio-container:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
container: python:3.8.2

services:
  minio:
    image: minio/minio:latest
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    env:
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: XXXX
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: XXXXX
```

I read a little bit and figured out that behind the scene github runs the `docker create service [OPTIONS] IMAGE_NAME` but I need to also be able to run `docker create service [OPTIONS] IMAGE_NAME COMMAND [ARGS]`

In case this is not implemented yet what are other options I can try?

Comment: I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64188150/1423507) [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64031598/1423507) if that could help.

Comment: GH community discussion on this topic: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/52675

Answer (score 1):

From a quick look at the Github Actions documentation this is not yet supported. You could easily get around this by using the Minio image from [Bitnami](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-minio) .

I believe something like this should work:

```
    services:
  minio:
    image: bitnami/minio:latest
    env:
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: minio
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: minio123
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    options: --name minio-server
```

Comment: It is better to use MinIO's official images published quay.io/minio/minio or minio/minio - Bitnami images are not supported by MinIO project.

Comment: https://github.com/bitnami/containers/tree/main/bitnami/minio

Comment: This answer doesn't address the overarching answer from the OP. The OP does want to use minio, but more than anything, the OP wants to know if command and argument parameters can be passed to a service container in GHA. This answer addresses that poorly.

Answer (score 0):

On a closer inspection, there is a way. But before I came to it, I tried a couple of ideas.
First I thought I can mount the directory with the source code into the container
and run one of the project files (a script) by specifying `--entrypoint` option,
but services are started before `git clone`.
Then I thought that maybe I can pass a command to the container, but no, that is not possible.
The third option I considered is passing a command via an environment
variable to some executable that comes with the image, supposedly a shell.
But shells can take a path to a script, not a command (`ENV` variable).
Then I thought, "let the service die," I just need to [restart the container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39329138/52499) after I clone the repository.
But that brings nothing to the table compared to...

"just create the container by hand." Which is what I did:

`.github/workflows/django.yml`:

```yaml
...
jobs:
    build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        container: python:3.5-alpine3.12
        steps:
            - uses: actions/checkout@v2
            - run: apk add expect && unbuffer ./create-cypress-container.sh
...
```

`create-cypress-container.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh -eux
apk add docker jq
network=$(docker inspect --format '{{json .NetworkSettings.Networks}}' `hostname` \
  | jq -r 'keys[0]')
docker pull -q cypress/base:12
docker run \
  -v /home/runner/work:/__w \
  -w "$GITHUB_WORKSPACE" \
  --name cypress \
  --network "$network" \
  -d \
  cypress/base:12 sh -xc 'ls && whoami && pwd'
sleep 10
docker ps
docker logs cypress
```

The job container is started with the following options (see `Initialize containers > Starting job containeir`):

```
...
--workdir /__w/PROJECT_NAME/PROJECT_NAME
-v "/home/runner/work":"/__w"
...
```

and environment variables:

```
...
GITHUB_WORKSPACE='/__w/PROJECT_NAME/PROJECT_NAME'
...
```

`/__w/PROJECT_NAME/PROJECT_NAME` is where your repository is cloned.

P.S. Having that said, I'm going to run front end and back end tests in separate jobs,
which should simplify matters and might eliminate the need to manually start containers.