# Creating a Minio(S3) container inside a github actions yml file

Tags: docker, yaml, containers, github-actions, minio

I am trying to create an Minio/S3 container so I can run my test suite as an action on github. I currently have the following:

```
name: Run Tests
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04

    services:
      postgres:
        ...

      minio:
        image: minio/minio
        volumes:
          - /data
        ports:
          - 9000:9000
        env:
          MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: minio
          MINIO_SECRET_KEY: minio123
        options: --entrypoint "minio server /data" --health-cmd "curl -f http://localhost:9000/minio/health/live" --health-interval 10s --health-timeout 5s --health-retries 5

    steps:
      ...
```

I have tried the following permutations to get the minio container to work but with no success:

```
volumes:
  - ./data:/data

volumes:
  - ./:/data

volumes:
  - .:/data

volumes:
  - /data:/data
```

And I even tried:

```
options: --entrypoint "mkdir /data; minio server /data" ...

options: --entrypoint "minio server /tmp" ...

options: --entrypoint ["minio server", "/tmp"] ...
```

And I have tried using the `-v` flag to mount volumes before the `--entrypoint` flag.

```
options: -v /s3_data:/data --entrypoint "minio server /data" ...

options: -v ${{ github.workspace }}/s3_data:/data --entrypoint "minio server /data" ...

options: -v ${{ github.workspace }}/s3_data:/data:rw --entrypoint "minio server /data" ...
```

In an attempt to get it to work. But unfortunately I get:

```
starting container process caused: exec: "minio server /data": stat minio server /data: no such file or directory: unknown
```

And I can't run the `minio server` without any argument :(

Comment: What is required to be mounted inside the container? Is is a directory from the GitHub repository?

Answer (score 8):

### TL;DR;

[There exists an ongoing GitHub Actions Community thread](https://github.community/t/job-service-command/16477) concerning the lack of support for setting `jobs.<job_id>.services.<service_id>.command` and
[this existing question is very similar to yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60849745/how-can-i-run-a-command-in-github-action-service-containers).

---

[You could extend the official image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64182487/1423507) as suggested by [@ahasbini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2949966/ahasbini) then build and push your [`docker image`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image/) to a [Docker Registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/) and use your own `image` in the [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) [`jobs.<job_id>.services.<service_id>.image`](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idservicesservice_idimage). For example:

The `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM minio/minio
CMD ["server", "/data", "--address=0.0.0.0:9000"]
```

> **Note**: you can use the [`lazybit/minio`](https://hub.docker.com/r/lazybit/minio) image I built for this answer.

The `job.<job_id>.services.<service_id>` spec:

```yaml
jobs:
  ...
  minio:
    name: minio
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      minio:
        image: lazybit/minio
        ports:
          - 9000:9000
        env:
          MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.MINIO_ACCESS_KEY }}
          MINIO_SECRET_KEY: ${{ secrets.MINIO_SECRET_KEY }}
        volumes:
          - ${{ github.workspace }}/data:/data
        options: --name=minio --health-cmd "curl http://localhost:9000/minio/health/live"
    steps:
      - run: pip3 install minio
      - run: |
            python3 - <<'EOF'
            from minio import Minio
            from minio.error import ResponseError

            try:
                minio = Minio(
                    'localhost:9000',
                    access_key='${{ secrets.MINIO_ACCESS_KEY }}',
                    secret_key='${{ secrets.MINIO_SECRET_KEY }}',
                    secure=False
                )
            except Exception as ex:
                raise

            minio.make_bucket('foo')
            minio.make_bucket('bar')
            print(f'{minio.list_buckets()}')
            EOF
```

> **Notes**:
>
> 1. The `minio/minio` images do not currently have a [`HEALTHCHECK`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck) instruction set (`docker inspect minio/minio:latest --format {{.Config.Healthcheck}}`) so we need to set the [`--health-cmd`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/#options) in the [`jobs.<job_id>.services.<service_id>.options`](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idservicesservice_idoptions) to hit [the services `livenessProbe` endpoint](https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-monitoring-guide.html) to make sure the service is running before we start running the [`jobs.<job_id>.steps`](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idsteps)
> 2. I had some issues connecting to the service by name so I set the `minio` endpoint to `locahost:9000`, the GitHub Actions are run in a [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) [`Pod`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/), [they share the same network namespace and are accessible via `localhost`](https://www.mirantis.com/blog/multi-container-pods-and-container-communication-in-kubernetes/)
> 3. Accessing [encrypted secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets) in the `jobs.<job_id>.services.<service_id>.env` and `jobs.<job_id>.steps.<step_id>.run`
> 4. Mounting a local directory as the volume backing the `minio` service using the [`github` context](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#github-context)'s `workspace`

[image: GitHub Actions minio service]

Comment: MinIO publishes a container for this purpose alone `minio/minio:edge-cicd` - https://hub.docker.com/layers/minio/minio/edge-cicd/images/sha256-29e8e51691d11e779468f275002779b221fd3902518d103e35c8a8bb2ef0f3ea?context=explore

Comment: @Harshavardhana Can you post an example using that minio/minio:edge-cicd image while also creating a specific bucket?

Comment: Here is a full working example: https://github.com/minio/minio/discussions/16099

Comment: The link to the GH Actions community thread is broken. I've started another one discussing this issue [here](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/52675). The question addresses the broader issue of passing commands to service containers, not necessarily the specifics of getting minio to run as a service container.

Answer (score 3):

The error is complaining about the `--entrypoint "minio server /data"`, not about the `volumes` configuration. It seems to be looking for a file called `minio server /data` rather than executing the command in a shell. Here's a [good explanation](https://medium.com/@oprearocks/how-to-properly-override-the-entrypoint-using-docker-run-2e081e5feb9d) of how `--entrypoint` flag works, the reason is because `--entrypoint` requires a file (either a binary file or a script) to execute and not the command with arguments to run. It appears that this is quite difficult to overcome as seen [here](https://github.community/t/how-do-i-properly-override-a-service-entrypoint/17435/6) as well.

The only suggestion I would think of is to build on top of the `minio/minio` Docker image with the arguments set in the `Dockerfile` and upload it to DockerHub so you could use it as the `image` instead.

Below is a sample `Dockerfile` you could use:

```
FROM minio/minio
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh", "minio", "server", "/data"]
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend this solution, but want to leave it out there in case somebody else is banging their head against a brick wall and wants a quick but convoluted solution.

---

In our workflow we added:

```yaml
    services:
      minio:
        # fixme: let's not depend on external unofficial image
        image: lazybit/minio
        ports:
          - 9000:9000
        env:
          MINIO_ROOT_USER: accesskey
          MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
        options: --name=minio --health-cmd "curl http://localhost:9000/minio/health/live"
    steps:
      - run: wget https://dl.min.io/client/mc/release/linux-amd64/mc
      - run: chmod +x ./mc
      - run: ./mc alias set minio http://127.0.0.1:9000 accesskey password
      - run: ./mc mb --ignore-existing minio/MY_BUCKET
```

I used the unofficial [lazybit/minio image](https://hub.docker.com/r/lazybit/minio) as it was the offical one would not run.

Basically, the github action create one image with all the other images "merged". So we knew we coud access the minio service at `http://localhost:9000`. Alas, there is no easy way to set a default bucket via env variable, but we had to create the bucket via [`mc`](https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-client-quickstart-guide.html).

---

A few gotchas:

- Minio uses `endpoint` over `url` in its config
- minio requires your `use_path_style_endpoint` to be set to true

In our case we used a laravel app so we had to define the filesystem config like this:

```
<?php


$envUsingMinIo = ['local', 'testing-local'];
$usesMinIo = in_array(
    needle: env('APP_ENV'),
    haystack: $envUsingMinIo,
    strict: true
);

return [
    'disks' => [
        ...,
        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'eu-west-1'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            // the below 'endpoint' url is actually used for minio:
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_URL'),
            // use older urls:
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => $usesMinIo,
        ],
    ],
];
```

It may differ for your client.