# How to create default bucket for minio within github actions using minio:edge-cicd?

Tags: docker, github-actions, minio

I want to add minio service in my github action for my end-to-tests. (It should mimick an Amazon S3 Bucket storage.)

I want to use the `minio/minio:edge-cicd` docker image.

In my yaml-file I have a job:

```
jobs:
  e2e:
    ...
    services:
      minio:
        image: minio/minio:edge-cicd
        env:
          MINIO_ROOT_USER: minio
          MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: minio123
```

Yet how do I create a default bucket named `my_bucket` for my minio service?

(And how can my service access the minio server? I assume it should be reachable at `localhost:9000` yet I run into a command timeout when executed on github actions. Yet that may stem from not having any bucket in that environment.)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Releated, yet no clear answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64031598/creating-a-minios3-container-inside-a-github-actions-yml-file

Comment: Found a workaround but its using a different, unoffical image, posted it there as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71855338/457268