# Install package in Docker image created by Spring Boot Maven plugin

Tags: spring-boot, docker, spring-boot-maven-plugin

My Spring Boot project contains the Spring Boot Maven Plugin which I use for building a Docker image by running `mvn spring-boot:build-image`.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>build-image</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When deploying this image to a Docker stack I need to run a healthcheck using the `curl` command but unfortunately `curl` is not installed by the default buildpack.

Is it possible to further tweak the image building process so that `curl` gets installed into the iamge? I couldn't find the necessary information

Answer (score 4):

**TLDR;**

Install `curl` into the build image with:

```
docker run --user="root" --entrypoint launcher my-app:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT "apt-get update && apt-get install curl -y"
```

Grab container id of the stopped container with `docker ps -a`:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                  COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                       PORTS     NAMES
2ff7db32825f   my-app:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT   "launcher 'apt-get u…"   44 minutes ago   Exited (0) 44 minutes ago              reverent_swanson
```

Create a new container image based on the one we installed `curl` into with:

```
docker commit 2ff7db32825f my-app-with-curl
```

Fire up a new container defining the correct `ENTRYPOINT` to start Spring Boot app:

```
docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 --user="cnb" --entrypoint /cnb/process/web my-app-with-curl
```

Now `curl` should be ready inside your container.

---

**Details of the solution:**

The reasoning behind Cloud Native Buildpacks (CNBs) & Paketo.io, which are basically abstracted away by the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`s `build-image` goal, is to free us from the need to write/maintain our own `Dockerfiles`. So the inversion of this is: It's easy to configure the build process, but it is not easy to change things like installed packages.

The reason is, that those packages are maintained in a so called [stack](https://buildpacks.io/docs/concepts/components/stack/), that manages the used `build`-time and `run`-time images. And if the stack doesn't define a [Mixin for your OS-level dependency](https://buildpacks.io/docs/concepts/components/stack/#mixins), then you can't simply add another package. It would also **not suffice** to [create your own simple buildpack](https://buildpacks.io/docs/buildpack-author-guide/create-buildpack/) (I tried this approach). And creating your own stacks, buildpacks and/or builders would also negate the huge benefits that Cloud Native Buildpacks provide! Amongst other things we would be also forced to keep the images updated ourselves...

**But there's another solution.** As we don't want to create our own stacks/buildpacks, we can tweak the container image which has been created by CNBs/`spring-boot-maven-plugin`. Because the official docs show us [how to hook into the startup process of the produced containers](https://buildpacks.io/docs/app-developer-guide/run-an-app/#user-provided-shell-process) and run shell scripts for example. Let's assume our `mvn spring-boot:build-image` command produced a container image called `my-app:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`.

Then first we install `curl` into the image with:

```
docker run --user="root" --entrypoint launcher my-app:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT "apt-get update && apt-get install curl -y"
```

We need to use `--user="root"` here in order that the command `apt-get update && apt-get install curl -y` will run successfully (otherwise we would run into errors like `List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (13: Permission denied)`). This will install curl, but we shouldn't use the resulting container in production. Because our Spring Boot app would run using the root user, which would introduce a variety of security problems. Also we've overwritten the `ENTRYPOINT` of our container, so it wouldn't be able to start our app.

Therefore we simply [start this stopped container with a new command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39329138/4964553), entrypoint & user! Simply grab the container ID of the stopped container with `docker ps -a`:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                  COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                       PORTS     NAMES
2ff7db32825f   my-app:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT   "launcher 'apt-get u…"   44 minutes ago   Exited (0) 44 minutes ago              reverent_swanson
```

And **create a new container image** based on the one we installed `curl` into with:

```
docker commit 2ff7db32825f my-app-with-curl
```

Finally **fire up a new container** based on this new image, defining the correct `ENTRYPOINT` to start our Spring Boot app and also using the `cnb` user again (as defined in the Cloud Native Buildpacks):

```
docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 --user="cnb" --entrypoint /cnb/process/web my-app-with-curl
```

---

**Off topic but relevant**:

There are ongoing discussions if it is desired to install curl in a production container. [See this post for example](https://blog.sixeyed.com/docker-healthchecks-why-not-to-use-curl-or-iwr/).

Comment: Can you explain a bit more one this - `It would also not suffice to create your own buildpack...`? I am trying to use [apt-buildpack](https://github.com/fagiani/apt-buildpack) to install other dependencies not curl.

Comment: What if I want to push the custom my-app-with-curl image? Should I create a new Dockerfile based on it and add an ENTRYPOINT line to it?

Comment: I didn't try it myself, but it should suffice to simply use another `docker commit` after you ran the `my-app-with-curl` with the correct entrypoint and user - and then simply `docker push` the resulting image.

Answer (score -2):

I ended up using a mounted volume (`/utils` for instance) with a static compiled curl (https://github.com/moparisthebest/static-curl) and configured health checker like

```
/utils/curl http://localhost:8080/actuator/health
```