# Run command line argument e.g. "apt-get install libfontconfig1" using spring-boot-maven-plugin creating docker image

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven, docker-image

I have a problem where I have a spring boot application with a docker container. In this one I need to install "libfontconfig1", because I need that somehow in my application that creates an excel file.
I don't have a dockerfile, I create the image with the spring boot maven plugin and it would be such a hassle to change my way of creating the docker image just for the sake of such a small font config file.
Any help is much appreciated! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install package in Docker image created by Spring Boot Maven plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63789255/install-package-in-docker-image-created-by-spring-boot-maven-plugin)

Comment: thanks for the answer. I had a look into this before submitting my question. I was hoping there was an easier way of doing this, e.g. just running this line of apt-get in the image creation process or anything. 
If I had to do it once it would be no problem but the container will be recreated automatically (jenkins & rancher) everytime something changes. So it has to be something automated as well

Comment: In the moment the only viable option is to create your own Dockerfile. The Buildpacks are not meant to change and do not fulfill your requirements

Comment: all right. Thanks for sharing your expertise! :)