# How to add custom files to the docker file system while creating image using 'cloud native buildpacks'

Tags: spring-boot, buildpack

I am trying to use Cloud Native Buildpacks in my SpringBoot Application, Can any one help me to understand how can I add custom files to the docker image file system and also how can I install extra packages while creating the image?

Comment: I think this will answer your question. Despite the title for this other post, it's not specific to native. It'll work with any app. [Is it possible to customize docker image generated with Spring Native (with buildpack)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69447497/is-it-possible-to-customize-docker-image-generated-with-spring-native-with-buil)