# Spring Boot in Docker build by buildpack cannot load Font

Tags: buildpack, spring-boot-gradle-plugin, paketo

My Spring Boot application runs in Docker and is build by `gradlew bootBuildImage`.
When run in Docker container application cannot load fonts

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.getVersion(Unknown Source)
```

Root cause seems to be missing `fontconfig` and  `ttf-dejavu` packages.
When using `Dockerfile`, one can easily install those packages using `apk add`, `yum`, `apt-get`, etc

But https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/spring-boot and https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica do not have option to install additional packages.

Is there buildpack (or configuration option) that will build Docker images with font support?

Comment: Check out this SO question. It's very similar and I think it'll answer your question. [Is it possible to customize docker image generated with Spring Native (with buildpack)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69447497/is-it-possible-to-customize-docker-image-generated-with-spring-native-with-buil)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the image after the fact. A sample Dockerfile would look like this:

```sh
FROM backend:latest

USER root # root for apt
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --assume-yes fontconfig && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/debconf/*

USER 1000:1000 # back to cnb user
```