Spring Boot Maven Plugin - build docker image with custom binary dependencies
I use spring-boot-maven-plugin to build docker images.
Under the hood, this uses buildpacks (paketo). My knowledge around buildpacks is very limited.
The problem is a new requirement: we will use the playwrite library. This library needs specific binaries to be installed in the host (browser engines, if I am not mistaken).
The Playwrite folks also have a custom docker image for this. If I would work with dockerfiles, I would simply use their image in mf FROM instruction.
But when it comes to buildpacks, is there a way to configure Spring Boot Maven Plugin to add the extra binaries on my image? Or should I migrate to some other maven plugin (like this one) that works with good-old dockerfiles and gain back explicit control over the image creation?
I have no specific reason to use buildpacks. I only used them because spring-boot-maven-plugin works with them. It is not clear to me if they are preferable to dockerfiles, so I am open to both trying to configure them to include the binaries, or, if this is not possible, to migrate to dockerfiles or some other alternative way to build docker images.

Are you using Playwrite at runtime with your application? I ask because it's a testing tool and the typical recommendation is to run builds & tests with your CI of choice and then make your container image with buildpacks. Making the container image is one of the last steps, after everything else has gone green in CI.

Yes, I use it to crawl some html pages.
I am not sure how could I convince buildpacks (through spring-boot-maven-plugin) to choose playwright base-image. After Alex Albu's response, I ended up abandoning spring-boot-maven-plugin and using docker-maven-plugin by fabric8.io. This plugin works with dockerfiles. In the dockerfile, I had the flexibility to choose the base image  I needed.

4.) here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/69466535/1585136 would be the easiest option. If there are Ubuntu packages for what you need.

1.) from that link is another possibility, but it's more work (probably roughly the same as writing a custom dockerfile). With the Paketo Java buildpacks, we publish Ubuntu base images but your base image for the stack can be most Linux images so long as Java can run on that image.

One way to do this would be to create a custom docker image and use another plugin to build it, like maven exec plugin.
Here is an example of a production ready docker image, like the one Buildpacks generates for you:
FROM eclipse-temurin:21 AS builder
WORKDIR workspace
ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} catalog-service.jar
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar catalog-service.jar extract

FROM eclipse-temurin:21
RUN useradd spring
USER spring
WORKDIR workspace
COPY --from=builder workspace/dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder workspace/spring-boot-loader/ ./
COPY --from=builder workspace/snapshot-dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder workspace/application/ ./
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]

You can customize this image as you see fit.
