# how to build OCI images with additional packages using Spring Boot buildpack

Tags: spring-boot, buildpack, spring-boot-gradle-plugin, paketo

I am using Spring Boot with Gradle plugin https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image
to build OCI images. This works fine for basic use case (web application packaged as jar inside image). I more customization for my images

- use curl to download some packages
- install and customize those packages inside image

How to configure gradle plugin to do those steps? Before migrating to OCI buildpacks, I had Dockerfile with bash commands. With buildpacks, I see no way to customize build so image will include additional software.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to customize docker image generated with Spring Native (with buildpack)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69447497/is-it-possible-to-customize-docker-image-generated-with-spring-native-with-buil)

Comment: This minimal invasive approach is maybe also a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65393843/4964553 Simply install packages (e.g. curl) into the resulting image after the buildpack build like this: `docker run --user="root" --entrypoint launcher my-app:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT "apt-get update && apt-get install curl -y"`. See the other steps necessary [in the linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65393843/4964553).