# Build C++ project against docker container not image

Tags: docker

I just started learning Docker and trying to build a C++ project for Windows on Ubuntu.
For that I use [this project](https://github.com/Dixaba/qt5-gcc-cross) which almost works, but I have linking error, particularly it fails to link against libssh.

I run the build of my project using this command:

```
sudo docker run -v $PWD:/project/source -v $PWD/build_docker:/project/build my_qt_cross_win:qttools
```

where `my_qt_cross_win:qttools` is the image that I built by git cloning original repo and added some missing libraries.

Since building it takes 2 hours, because it builds the whole system, and I just need to fix this minor linking issue, I would like to just add the proper libssh.a to the container that was instanced from `my_qt_cross_win:qttools` image and build my project using that modified container. But it feels like I can use only images for that, because docker complains

```
Unable to find image 'musing_chebyshev:latest' locally
```

when I try to use container name or id instead of an image.

```
$ sudo docker container ps -a                                                                                                                                             
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
d207fd2d9dd8        my_qt_cross_win:qttools     "/bin/sh -c 'qmake /…"   11 minutes ago      Exited (2) 10 minutes ago                       musing_chebyshev
```

Is there any way I can use a modified container to build my project?

Comment: not really programming related, `docker run` creates a new container. You want [`docker start`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/start/) to resume your existing container

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353055/how-to-start-a-stopped-docker-container-with-a-different-command

Comment: @AlanBirtles thank you for the hint. I just needed to copy the missing file to the existing container and make an image from that container using `docker commit`. So it turned out that no need to build the image again, I can just commit the changes and a new image is ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply needed to copy the missing file to the existing container:

```
sudo docker cp -a d207fd2d9dd8:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.a .
```

And then commit the changes to the container to create a new image:

```
sudo docker commit d207fd2d9dd8 my_qt_cross_win/libssh_static
```

Then the new image appeared:

```
$ sudo docker images                                                                                                                               
REPOSITORY                         TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
my_qt_cross_win/libssh_static    latest              9f7af733526b        21 hours ago        3.43GB
```

Though it did not solve my original issue, this was the answer I expected to get to reuse my existing container for build. Thanks to @AlanBirtles for the link.