# Is there any way to start a Docker container with an interactive terminal?

Tags: docker

Currently I start my docker container using:

```sh
docker run -it myimage
```

However I'm trying to create a base container then re-using the container instead of re-creating one.

```
docker create mycontainer:myimage
docker start --it mycontainer
```

I want to be able to do the above. To create it first, then start it in `--it` mode. However this doesn't seem to be a valid option. I've tried using `-a` or `-i`, but they both don't seem to work properly. The console gets messed up because it's trying to read from stdin but there's no input.

Comment: It seems, for a pre-existing container, once it's running, you need to add one more command: e.g.
docker exec -it <containerID> /bin/bash

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start a stopped Docker container with a different command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353055/how-to-start-a-stopped-docker-container-with-a-different-command)

Comment: Why not delete and recreate the container when the process completes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker containers have three states.

[image]

`docker create` command creates a container from an image.

`docker start` command starts the container. there is no option to assign a virtual terminal(-t;-tty) for the container

To use the tty option, use the [foreground mode of the docker run command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#foreground) or run the [exec command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) in an already running container.

`docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]`

`docker exec [OPTIONS] CONTAINER COMMAND [ARG...]`