How can I list the files, or explore the files, inside a stopped docker container?
I have a Docker container which has crashed due to a bug in the containerized application.
The restart policy was set to unless-stopped, which was causing the container to start, immediatly crash, and then restart again.
I changes the restart policy using docker container update --restart=no <container-name>.
I would like to download (copy) the log file from the container to the host machine so that I can inspect it to find out what went wrong.
If the container were running, I would simply be able to run docker exec -it <container-name> bash to start a bash session within the container. I would then be able to navigate the file system, find the log file, and either inspect it within the container or copy it from the container with docker cp.
However, the container is not running, and cannot be started because it will immediatly crash.
What are my options in this situation?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353055/how-to-start-a-stopped-docker-container-with-a-different-command and then exec , or docker export

a) In your dockerfile, you could change your entrypoint to:
CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]

b) Or
Commit the stopped container:
docker commit $STOPPED_CONTAINER user/test_image

Start/run with a different entry point:
docker run -it --entrypoint=sh user/test_image

c) Or you could try docker debug: https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/debug/

Great idea - but Docker Debug requires a Pro, Teams, or Business Subcription.

If I change the Dockerfile, wouldn't this require re-building the image? Which surely would blow away the old image and container containing the log file?

Yes, maybe you need to write your logs out of the container. Check: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/18078, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353055/how-to-start-a-stopped-docker-container-with-a-different-command

There are multiple solutions for that:

docker logs CONTAINER shows what was going on inside of the container.

change the entry point to sh or bash and debug it:
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint bash CONTAINER_IMAGE




The logs are saved to a file, not stdout, so docker logs won't work here. Sorry, should have been more specific in the original question.

I just accidentally destroyed the container, but I think that second option might have worked well. Next time it crashes, I'll test it
