# Docker, Kitematic, running terminal commands

Tags: docker, kitematic

I am using Docker with Kitematic and I have installed an image of Linux with Magento 2 on it.

It all works well, but Magento 2 requires that I run terminal commands for several things. How do I do this?

I know where the terminal is and there's Docker CLU, but when I go to the actual Magento directory, there's only the app but no bin/magento? So how does this work, or, in other words, where do I run the root commands from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has already been asked and answered. Just run

```
docker exec -it <container_id_or_name> /bin/bash
```

Check the link below.

[How do I run a command on an already existing Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26153686/how-to-run-a-command-on-an-already-existing-docker-container)