# How to restart container using container-id?

Tags: docker

I created a container using the command

```
docker run ubuntu /bin/bash -c "echo 'cool content' > /tmp/cool-file"
```

Now I see the container has exited

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
9e5017aef3f9        ubuntu              "/bin/bash -c 'echo '"   38 seconds ago      Exited (0) 36 seconds ago                       elegant_euler
```

Question: How can I restart and get in to the interactive mode for this container using its **container-id**?
I cannot use `docker run -it <image_name>` since this expects image name and not container id.
I tried using docker attach  , but I think this only works for running containers.
I don't want to commit this container just yet so, how can I restart and get in to interactive mode for this container using it's container-id?
EDIT: I'm able to get in to other containers using `docker start {container-id}` and then running `docker attach {container-id}`. I wonder if there is something peculiar with the way I created the container which would result in this behavior. I'm just starting out with docker so do direct me in right direction if I'm missing some basic bit.

Comment: Is not the best solution, but I'm using [portainer](http://portainer.io) to manage my docker images.

Comment: Check this documentation - https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockerizing/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a command on an already existing docker container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26153686/how-to-run-a-command-on-an-already-existing-docker-container)

Comment: You can't for a short running process.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/30269330/1318694 in the above dupe deals with if a container exits before you can use `docker exec` on it.

Comment: also https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/19746

Comment: @Matt I've already seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26153686/how-to-run-a-command-on-an-already-existing-docker-container but OP there was more concerned with restarting his container (let it be image name) whereas I'm particularly interested in restarting the container with container-id.

Comment: @AnukuL Did you try this https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/restart/ ?

Comment: @Prabhakar Yes, but with no luck.

Comment: @AnukuL Didn't that restart the container?

Comment: @Prabhakar No, It didn't restart the container

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A container exits when it completes its command. So the container started with

```
docker run ubuntu /bin/bash -c "echo 'cool content' > /tmp/cool-file"
```

will exit as soon as the command `echo` is completed. In this case it doesn't make sense to restart that container.

If you run a new container in detached mode you'll be able to keep it live and to attach it in a second time.

So, in your case you should run a new container from the image in detached mode running a command like `/bin/bash` , then you can run the echo and attach it

```
docker run -d -ti ubuntu /bin/bash
docker exec -ti <containerId> /bin/bash -c "echo 'cool content' > /tmp/cool-file"
```

The container will be kept alive, so you can exec more commands on it, e.g.
docker exec -ti  /bin/bash -c "cat /tmp/cool-file"

or run a new /bin/bash to "attach" your container and to work in it as a command prompt

```
docker exec -ti <containerId> /bin/bash
root@<containerId>:/# cat /tmp/cool-file 
cool content
```

You can succesfully stop / start /restart this container

```
docker stop <containerId> && docker start <containerId>
```

or

```
docker restart <containerId>
```

Remind that when you restart a container it executes again its original command. So if you would able to restart the container of your use case (but you dont't) it would run again `/bin/bash -c "cat /tmp/cool-file"`

Restarting a container that run with command /bin/bash , it will run again the same command when restarting.

You normally can't change the command to RUN when restarting an existing container; to do it you can try some tricks as suggested at [How to start a stopped docker container with a different command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353055/how-to-start-a-stopped-docker-container-with-a-different-command).

Answer (score 15):

i tried myself:

```
docker restart <container_id>

docker exec -it <container_id> bash
```

works both perfect to restart and get into interactive terminal.

Answer (score 3):

Check [Docker `start` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/start/)

```
docker stop {containerId} && docker start -i {containerId}
```

Comment: There is no -t flag to docker start command. Also I added an edit to my question to be more precise.