# How to run command after initialization

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to run specific command after initialization of deployment is successful.

This is my yaml file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
        labels:
          app: auth
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: {{my-service-image}}
          env:
          - name: NODE_ENV
            value: "docker-dev"
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 100Mi
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
```

However, I would like to run command for db migration after (not before) deployment is successfully initialized and pods are running.

I can do it manually for every pod (with kubectl exec), but this is not very scalable.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

I resolved it using [lifecycles](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
        labels:
          app: auth
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: {{my-service-image}}
          env:
          - name: NODE_ENV
            value: "docker-dev"
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 100Mi
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
          lifecycle:
            postStart:
              exec:
                command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", {{cmd}}]
```

Comment: great answer for something that works in a command line and in the same container, but I would like to do this in a separate container that runs to completion and goes away like an init-container

Comment: @Rhubarb Personally I solved it creating a special management Pod, in which I run all the commands before deploying the app itself.

Comment: be careful cause according tho the documentation, there is not garantee that the postStart is called after or before the container entry point is called.

Comment: Yes, but since entrypoint and postStart are allegedly running asynchronously, you can add a sleep command as a last resort.

Comment: Do you add sleep to ensure poststart finishes before the entrypoint starts?

Comment: unfortunately, if your replicas is more than 1, your command will be executed more than once

Comment: Thanks. Works well. I have NFS server pod running. Whenever the new pod starts, the mounted filesystem automatically has index.html created onto it. I could move that using the post start script.

Comment: thank you :  command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "npx prisma generate"]

Answer (score 18):

You can use [Helm](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm) to deploy a set of Kubernetes resources. And then, use a [Helm hook](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/), e.g. `post-install` or `post-upgrade`, to run a [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/) in a separate docker container. Set your Job to invoke db migration. A Job will run >=1 Pods to completion, so it fits here quite well.

Answer (score 3):

I chose to use a [readinessProbe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/)
My application requires configuration after the process has completely started.
The postStart command was running before the app was ready.

```
readinessProbe:
  exec:
    command: [healthcheck]
  initialDelaySeconds: 30
  periodSeconds: 2
  timeoutSeconds: 1
  successThreshold: 3
  failureThreshold: 10
```

Comment: As per my understanding this will execute this command time to time not only once

Comment: Check the link I provided. I think you are referring to a liveness probe.

Comment: @D.Fitz so using this config, when app is ready will run "healthcheck"? What is exactly healthcheck, an script? Must be bash? can be something like Python/Node/PHP?

Comment: @MáximaAlekz the command will execute inside the container. You can use any command the container is equipped to handle.

Comment: @D.Fitz So an example of using bash would be `[ "/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hella" ]`?

Comment: You could use [startupProbe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-startup-probes) instead of `readinessProbe` to have it run only before the container is ready and until it succeeds. After that, it won't run and the `readinessProbe` will run instead.

Comment: The role of readiness and lifeness prob is not to execute commands that have side effects. They are here just to do what their names say. Check the health of the pod.