# Kubernetes pod yaml: source command does not work

Tags: bash, kubernetes, yaml, command, kubernetes-pod

In the following pod yaml, I cannot get `source` command to work. Initially I inserted the command under `args` between [`echo starting` and `echo done`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33887194/how-to-set-multiple-commands-in-one-yaml-file-with-kubernetes) and now I tried [`{.lifecycle.postStart}`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44140593/how-to-run-command-after-initialization) to no avail.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mubu62
  labels:
    app: mubu62
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mubu621
    image: dockreg:5000/mubu6:v6
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    ports:
    - containerPort: 5021
    command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
    args: 
    - echo starting;
      echo CONT1=\"mubu621\" >> /etc/environment;
      touch /mubu621;
      sed -i 's/#Port 22/Port 5021/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config;
      sleep 3650d;
      echo done;
    lifecycle:
      postStart:
        exec:
          command: ["/bin/bash","-c","source /etc/environment"]
  - name: mubu622
    image: dockreg:5000/mubu6:v6
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    ports:
    - containerPort: 5022
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred
  nodeName: spring
  restartPolicy: Always
```

`Kubectl apply` throws no errors, but `echo $CONT1` returns nada! `mubu6` is an ubuntu modified image.

The reason I am doing this, is because when I `ssh` from another pod in this pod `(mubu621)`, Kubernetes environment variables set through `env` are not seen in the `ssh` session.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `"/bin/bash","-c","source /etc/environment"` starts a session, source /etc/environment, then dissapear right away. That's why you cannot access variables sourced.

Comment: Should I also add a `sleep` command after that then? Under `args` where I do have a `sleep` command in the end, it also did not work.

Comment: I now used `["/bin/bash","-c","source /etc/environment","sleep 3650d"]`, but I still cannot `echo $CONT1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After experimenting with the suggestions under [set-environment-variable-automatically-upon-ssh-login](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101168/set-environment-variable-automatically-upon-ssh-login-no-root-access), what worked was to substitute

```
echo CONT1=\"mubu621\" >> /etc/environment;
```

with

```
echo CONT1=\"mubu621\" >> /root/.bashrc;
```

and delete

```
lifecycle:
      postStart:
        exec:
          command: ["/bin/bash","-c","source /etc/environment"]
```

that didn't work anyway.

Upon SSH-ing from `container mubu622` to `container mubu621`, I can now successfully execute `echo $CONT1` with `mubu621` output, **without having to `source` `/root/.bashrc` first**, which was initially the case with writing the `env_variable` in `/etc/environment`.

**In summary:** when using a `bash shell` in `kubernetes containers`, you can `SSH` from another container and `echo` variables written in `/root/.bashrc` without sourcing (because `kubernetes env_variables` are not available in a ssh session).
This is very useful e.g in the case of **multi-container pods**, so you know amongst other things in which container you are currently logged in.

Answer (score 1):

### TLDR

Move the env variable into `env` section of your pod spec:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mubu62
  labels:
    app: mubu62
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mubu621
    image: dockreg:5000/mubu6:v6
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    ports:
    - containerPort: 5021
    command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
    env:
    - name: CONT1
      value: mubu621
```

### Explanation

As one of the comments already indicated - your `source` command probably works, but only in the context where it's executed. If you'd like this to be applied for other commands - use the `env` field of the container spec. Consider this minimalistic example, using busybox:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox
  labels:
    app: busybox
spec:
  containers:
  - name: busybox
    image: busybox
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-ec", "sleep 1000"]
    env:
    - name: TEST_ENV
      value: "test_val"
```

with this - when you run the `env` command inside the pod - you'll see the `TEST_ENV` appear as expected:

```
$ kubectl exec -it busybox-6d467f94db-sj9nz env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=busybox-6d467f94db-sj9nz
TERM=xterm
TEST_ENV=test_val
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP=tcp://10.96.0.1:443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO=tcp
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT=443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR=10.96.0.1
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=10.96.0.1
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT=443
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS=443
KUBERNETES_PORT=tcp://10.96.0.1:443
HOME=/root
```

Read more about env variables in pods in [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/)

Comment: Thanks a lot andrzejwp, but as I mention in my question, I have already tried your suggestion, but does not work when I `ssh` from another pod. I want a variable I can `echo` in a `ssh session`.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get that part initially. But if you're SSH-ing into the pod and want that env set for each connection - I think you should look at the SSH configuration, or even the shell itself. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101168/set-environment-variable-automatically-upon-ssh-login-no-root-access

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction andrzejwp.