# Docker - extend the parent's ENTRYPOINT

Tags: postgresql, docker

I've got a custom image based on the official postgres image and I want to extend the entrypoint of the parent image so that it would create new users and databases if they don't exist yet every time a container starts up. Is it possible? Like my image would execute all the commands from the standard entrypoint plus my own shell script.

I know about putting my own scripts into the /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d directory, but it seems that they get executed only when the volume is created the first time.

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reuse inherited image's CMD or ENTRYPOINT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42280792/reuse-inherited-images-cmd-or-entrypoint)

Comment: This is a good writeup on the topic. https://superuser.com/a/1460890/926062

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you need to do is something like below

**setup_user.sh**

```
sleep 10
echo "execute commands to setup user"
```

**setup.sh**

```
sh setup_user.sh &
./docker-entrypoint.sh postgres
```

And your image should use the ENTRYPOINT as

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/setup.sh"]
```

You need to start your setup script in background and let the origin entryscript do its works to start the database

Comment: Seems to be a good one, thanks. I was also thinking of adding a script into the image which is supposed to be run manually, modifying it whenever I need new users/databases and executing it manually via the terminal attaching to the container.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer [Docker - extend the parent's ENTRYPOINT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46432769/docker-extend-the-parents-entrypoint/46433245#46433245), instead of sleeping a specific time, you may want to consider executing your script similar to how ''docker-entrypoint.sh'' of the postgres docker image does it ([docker-entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh); to init the DB, they start the server, execute initialization commands, and shut it down again). Thus:

**setup_user.sh**

```
su - "$YOUR_PG_USER" -c '/usr/local/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -o "-c listen_addresses='localhost'" -w start'
psql -U "$YOUR_PG_USER" "$YOUR_PG_DATABASE" < "$YOUR_SQL_COMMANDS"
su - "$YOUR_PG_USER" -c '/usr/local/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -m fast -w stop'
```

**setup.sh**

```
./setup_user.sh && ./docker-entrypoint.sh postgres
```