# Custom Docker image doesn't inherit CMD

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have an image built using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7-fpm
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint"]
```

It uses a custom entrypoint which is the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
echo "STARTING PHP FPM, CMD $@"
docker-php-entrypoint "$@"
```

The command of the parent image defined in it's [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/05fe6f9eb601984e5f95057578ce830a21d11716/7.1/jessie/fpm/Dockerfile) is `CMD ["php-fpm"]`

Now I expected this command to be inherited in my image. However, when I run the image, the command is empty. Here is the output of the `docker run` command:

> STARTING PHP FPM, CMD

However, if I copy `CMD ["php-fpm"]` to the end of my custom `Dockerfile`, the output is

> STARTING PHP FPM, CMD php-fpm
>
> [01-Nov-2017 20:04:02] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 7
>
> [01-Nov-2017 20:04:02] NOTICE: ready to handle connections

Why isn't the parent's `CMD` directive inherited?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This behavior is trying to be more intuitive, but I agree that it's a bit confusing. You see the [original issue here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/5147). That problem was that most people defining the `ENTRYPOINT` in a child image no longer wanted the `CMD` from the parent image.

With the current behavior, if you define an `ENTRYPOINT` in a child image, the `CMD` from the parent image will be null'd out, so you'll need to redefine it if you need to have it set.