Run default CMD from inherited docker image as well as your own CMD
I want to be able to run the inherited image CMD as well as my own without knowing what the default CMD is for the inherited image. Is this possible?
So if I did know the default CMD then the Dockerfile would look like this:
from main:latest
CMD echo "inherited command" && echo "my command"

Or perhaps there is another way around this. Currently we are running the image. Docker exec into it and then starting our command with "sh start.sh" so that both are running. Any help would be great! Thanks

Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42280792/596285

Can you run the existing container as-is, and run a second container from the same image overriding the command?  Docker's standard setup is that a container only runs a single process.

@DavidMaze unfortunately I need both processes to run on the same container

@BMitch yes very similar. Let's say that only the inherited CMD needs to run in the foreground and the other script doesn't. Is there something I can do in the Dockerfile to achieve this?
