# docker exec wrong with remote docker host in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, docker, jenkins-pipeline

I use Jenkins + Pipeline + DockerPlugin to build and run docker container with remote host, when execute command with the follow:

```
docker.withServer("tcp://192.168.1.122:2375",'') {
    def wait_results = sh(script: "docker exec -t development-taxpayer-server-131-1 echo aaa", returnStdout: true)
    print wait_results
}
```

> wait_results : nothing to print

the expect result is print 'aaa' in Jenkins console log.

the remote docker version is:

```
Client:
 Version:      1.12.5
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.4
 Git commit:   7392c3b
 Built:        Fri Dec 16 02:23:59 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.5
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.4
 Git commit:   7392c3b
 Built:        Fri Dec 16 02:23:59 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Comment: I have the same Issue. Did you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

Try instead

```
def wait_results = sh(script: "docker ps -a", returnStdout: true)
```

That way you can at least check that:

- docker is working
- the container `development-taxpayer-server-131-1` is running

Then, considering the [`docker exec` syntax](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/), try `-it`:

```
def wait_results = sh(script: "docker exec -it development-taxpayer-server-131-1 echo aaa", returnStdout: true)
```

Note: "[How to run a command on an already existing docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27708039/6309)" shows the same echo done without any option:

```
docker exec development-taxpayer-server-131-1 echo aaa
```

Comment: thanks, with your code it work well, this problem only when use "docker exec -t"

Comment: @herryliq the goal was to know if you see the container in a running state

Comment: @herryliq I have edited the answer, using the proper syntax for `docker exec`

Comment: if use docker exec -it, jenkins will retun some error and exit the job.
[docker-temp] Running shell script
+ docker exec -it production-taxpayer-server-129-1 echo aaa
cannot enable tty mode on non tty input

Comment: @herryliq OK, and without any option? Without -t -i?

Comment: yes, it will all same result. 
but when I use 'docker -h tcp://x.x.x.x:2375 exec development-taxpayer-server-131-1 echo aaa' with terminal, it work well.
I think it will some bug in Jenkins docker plugin.

Comment: @herryliq that is possible. The closest bug I see is https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41474