# How do I run a docker container by its container name?

Tags: docker

For example once I create a container with name of "duplo":

`docker run --name="duplo" -it /bin/bash -c "sudo /build/backup.sh"`.

How do I execute an additional command within the container after it exits? I can see it listed by `docker ps -a`.

Comment: `commit` and then `run`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30269330/118613

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as it is stopped, you can do nothing.

Maybe you can start it

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/start/

see the doc

and if it says running, you can connect and launch some commands using

`docker exec -it duplo bash`

or maybe just modify a string in a file

`docker exec -it duplo sed...`

, see the associated doc

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

Answer (score 5):

`docker start` is the command I was looking for.

`docker start -ia duplo`