# How to execute command inside of container from hosts directly?

Tags: linux, docker

If we've to do some operations(execute commands) inside of docker container, we can go inside it and then execute commands -

```
docker exec -it <ContainerId> bash   # go inside of container
cd /usr/local/tomcat/bin             # hit command inside of container
./catalina.sh start                  # hit command inside of container
```

After this we need to hit Ctrl + C to come out of container.

But without going inside of container, can we execute commands inside of it from host directly like -

```
   // command to attach to container
   // command 1 to execute
   // command 2 to execute
   // no command required to come out of container as above commands directly hit from hosts
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run a command on an already existing Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26153686/how-do-i-run-a-command-on-an-already-existing-docker-container)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can run your command at once:

```
docker exec -it <ContainerId> /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh start
```

if you need to run multiple commands, you can pass them straight to bash:

```
docker exec -it <ContainerId> bash -c 'command1 && command2'
```